# How to classify my numpy files in categories (Python)?

Tags: python, numpy

Let 's suppose that I have 500 numpy files where I must make some analyses, so I calculate for each file its own HW, all those HW are stored in a table which I call tempHW. Based on this table,  I  look at every trace and decide which group it belongs in. I make a list of lists of traces, then  I can loop through my list of traces and append each trace to the right category.

```
path ='C:\\Users\\user\\Test\\F_Key'

traces= os.listdir(path)  
print(len(traces)) 

tempHW=[6, 5, 6, 3, 3, 7, 4, 2, 5, 1, 4, 2, 5, 4, 3, 4, 5, 6, 4, 5, 5, 3, 1, 4, 4, 2, 3, 3, 4,
        4, 5, 4, 5, 3, 5, 4, 3, 6, 2, 5, 2, 6, 5, 3, 5, 5, 5, 2, 5, 6, 3, 3, 4, 6, 4, 4, 6, 6,
        6, 5, 4, 3, 5, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 6, 3, 0, 3, 3, 5, 5, 4, 7, 4, 5, 3, 3, 4, 4, 6, 4, 5, 4,
        6, 3, 3, 0, 3, 6, 4, 2, 2, 7, 5, 5, 4, 5, 4, 4, 4, 5, 2, 6, 6, 5, 5, 2, 4, 2, 6, 5, 4,
        3, 4, 5, 4, 4, 3, 5, 1, 5, 5, 3, 5, 6, 3, 4, 6, 5, 3, 5, 6, 5, 4, 5, 7, 3, 4, 4, 6, 4,
        4, 4, 6, 6, 6, 3, 8, 6, 3, 3, 5, 3, 3, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 4, 2, 2, 4, 3, 5, 4, 4, 6, 5, 5, 
        3, 3, 4, 5, 4, 4, 3, 5, 6, 5, 7, 4, 6, 4, 4, 4, 6, 3, 3, 5, 6, 5, 3, 5, 3, 3, 2, 6, 4,
        5, 2, 2, 5, 3, 5, 4, 4, 2, 5, 4, 5, 3, 4, 4, 5, 3, 4, 3, 6, 5, 3, 5, 5, 4, 3, 3, 4, 7,
        6, 6, 4, 3, 3, 4, 4, 3, 4, 5, 5, 4, 5, 3, 5, 6, 3, 4, 4, 2, 5, 3, 0, 4, 4, 2, 4, 4, 5,
        4, 5, 4, 4, 2, 5, 4, 5, 5, 1, 2, 6, 5, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 1, 4, 6, 5, 5, 5, 7, 4, 4, 3, 6,
        3, 3, 3, 4, 3, 5, 3, 2, 4, 5, 5, 4, 5, 4, 3, 6, 3, 4, 6, 2, 6, 5, 2, 5, 2, 5, 6, 3, 4,
        5, 5, 3, 4, 3, 8, 6, 4, 7, 4, 4, 3, 5, 4, 5, 3, 4, 6, 6, 4, 1, 3, 2, 6, 5, 4, 2, 6, 2,
        6, 2, 3, 3, 5, 3, 4, 5, 1, 3, 4, 5, 4, 5, 2, 2, 4, 6, 5, 2, 2, 5, 5, 4, 4, 2, 3, 4, 3,
        3, 4, 3, 1, 3, 2, 4, 3, 3, 3, 2, 5, 5, 6, 3, 4, 2, 2, 6, 5, 5, 4, 5, 4, 1, 5, 4, 4, 6, 
        7, 2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 2, 4, 6, 5, 4, 3, 5, 2, 5, 4, 5, 3, 6, 4, 4, 5, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 2, 6,
        3, 6, 4, 5, 4, 2, 4, 4, 2, 4, 6, 4, 4, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 6, 5, 2, 6, 3, 5, 4, 4,
        6, 2, 4, 3, 6, 4, 5, 3, 4, 2, 4, 4, 5, 3, 2, 5, 6, 5, 3, 6, 3, 4, 3, 3, 5, 1, 3, 3, 4,
        4, 5, 6, 2, 5, 5, 3]
print(len(tempHW))
tempTracesHW = [[] for _ in range(9)]
for i in range(len(traces)):
    HW = tempHW[i]
    filepath= os.path.join(path, traces[i])
    trace, = np.load(filepath)
    tempTracesHW[HW].append(trace)
print (tempTracesHW)
```

Then, I convert this list in a numpy table.

```
tempTracesHW =  np.array([np.array(tempTracesHW[HW]).astype('float32') for HW in range(9)])
print(tempTracesHW.shape)
print(tempTracesHW[5].shape)
```

However my code planted when it arrived to those lines:

```
 for trace in os.listdir(path):
           tempTracesHW[HW].append([np.load(os.path.join(path, trace))])
```

I don't know  really how to resolve this problem, when debugging, my code is totally blocked,

Answer (score 0):

This will work for me:

```
    tempTracesHW = [ [] for _ in range(9)]
    for i in range(len(traces)):
        HW = tempHW[i]
        tempTracesHW[HW].append( np.load(os.path.join(path, traces[i])) )

    tempTracesHW = np.array( [np.array(tempTracesHW[HW]).astype('float32') for HW in range(9)] )
```

> **Input**: For `classify 6` two:

```
    [array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
           [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
           [10, 11, 12, 13, 14]])]
```

> **Output**:

```
    tempTracesHW.shape=9
    tempTracesHW[6].shape=(2, 3, 5)
    array([[[  0.,   1.,   2.,   3.,   4.],
            [  5.,   6.,   7.,   8.,   9.],
            [ 10.,  11.,  12.,  13.,  14.]],

           [[  0.,   1.,   2.,   3.,   4.],
            [  5.,   6.,   7.,   8.,   9.],
            [ 10.,  11.,  12.,  13.,  14.]]], dtype=float32)
```

***Tested with Python:3.4.2 - numpy:1.8.2***

Comment: firstly, the 9 empty lists, are my lists which I will use to classify my files, secondly, for the imbrication of loops I correct that, thirdly, I correct that I use  HW , I forget it, fourth, I want to convert my 9 lists which contains my numpy files into a 9 tables. Finally,  I still not have the best classification.